# Intellij not showing variable names for custom library methods

Tags: intellij-idea, intellisense

I have built a custom library to modularize the code in my project and one of the methods is void `sendOtp(String mobile, String message, String otp)`

There are a bunch of such methods in the library and so I don't remember the order of the arguments in all the methods, I rely on IntelliJ to provide me with the suggestions. But when I try to call this method in my main project, the IntellJ IntelliSense doesn't seem to suggest the right parameter names. It's driving my ocd side nuts. How do I get this right?

I am on Java 1.8 and I am using Maven for both the project and the library.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the sources of the library attached to it?

Comment: no. I mean It's a custom library and so the jar is present locally in my .m2 folder. But for example when I go to the definition of this method it gives me an option to download the sources but fails to download it. So that's how I assume the answer to your question is NO. Let me know if I got it wrong.

Comment: Is there JavaDoc available for this library and attached to it? It looks like the library is compiled without debug info, so the `.class` files do not have the information about method parameter names, therefore IDE cannot suggest you the original names.

Comment: I do have javadoc for another method and that behaves just the same, no param names.. all s1, s2 etc. I didn't get this part in your comment `looks like the library is compiled without debug info`. What do I do to compile it with `debug info`? Both library and project use Maven

Comment: You need to have the sources for the library. But in case you do have them, you can just attach the sources to the library and the hints will start working for method names.

Comment: Okay let me try it.

Comment: That worked! Attaching sources of the library to the project did the trick! Thanks a lot @CrazyCoder! I can't mark it as an answer since it's a comment. But timely help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class files compiled without debug info do not contain parameter name information. For the IDE hints to work properly you can attach the sources to the library.